# Best way sending ExecuteReader result over http

Tags: c#, sql, rest, http, executereader

What is the best way, sending the result of ADO.NETs [ExecuteReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) over http to an client (the client pulls the data of course).

I don't want to load the result into an `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` serialize it and so on, becuase this seems to produce a lot of over head.

Is there a method, to send the data as a binary format over http?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use a BinaryFormatter ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx ) to serialize a List<x> or DataTable in a binary format.

Comment: I will take a look at the BinaryFormatter. But is there  way, to go without serialization?

Comment: Another option would be to just allow the client to execute queries direct against the database.

Comment: Thats the way we are working currently, but we want to implement a new abstraction level, because we need to deal with mobile clients, windows clients... Another reason is, that our controllers in the http endpoint has special user access rights, so our security concept is build on top of it.

Comment: @Dan-o the BinaryFormatter seems to be not very effective: http://www.maxondev.com/serialization-performance-comparison-c-net-formats-frameworks-xmldatacontractserializer-xmlserializer-binaryformatter-json-newtonsoft-servicestack-text/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way in my opinion is building a custom class with the table fields as class members, then send plain array with each row as a new instance:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

public void Foo()
{
    string strSQL = "Select * From Cars";

    List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
    //...initialize connection, Command, etc...
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        cars.Add(new Car {
            Model = reader["Model"] + "", 
            Price = (int)reader["Price"]
        });
    }
    //...send cars.ToArray() over to client...
}
```

This way you send only the data you need, with zero overhead.

If you want to make it flexible and support any table structure, you'll need some more classes. Most basic thing I can think of, are such classes:

```
public class BasicField
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public class BasicRow
{
    public BasicField[] Fields { get; set; }
}

public class BasicTable
{
    public BasicRow[] Rows { get; set; }

    public static BasicTable Parse(DataTable table)
    {
        string[] fieldNames = table.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().ToList().ConvertAll(c => c.Caption).ToArray();
        List<BasicRow> basicRows = table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().ToList().ConvertAll(dataRow =>
        {
            List<BasicField> fields = new List<BasicField>();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataRow.ItemArray.Length; i++)
                fields.Add(new BasicField
                {
                    Name = fieldNames[i], 
                    Value = dataRow.ItemArray[i]
                });
            return new BasicRow
            {
                Fields = fields.ToArray()
            };
        });
        return new BasicTable
        {
            Rows = basicRows.ToArray()
        };
    }
}
```

Then to use it, such code is required:

```
BasicTable basicTable;
string strSQL = "Select * From Cars";
using (DataTable table = new DataTable())
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, connection))
    {
        adapter.Fill(table);
    }
    basicTable = BasicTable.Parse(table);
}
```

And you can send `basicTable` over to the client, being made from minimal primitive members, it should have minimum overhead.

Comment: The problem is, that i don't have any model, because the SQL is very dynamic.

Comment: @BendEg you mean you need to be able to send anything? No restrictions whatsoever?

Comment: Yes, thats correct. Anything that can be returned from the db - so anything :) But i some cases, i have for example 20000 rows with 20 columns, so i want to get as much performance as possible.

Comment: @Ben see my edit, this should do what you asked for.

Comment: Thank you, i will make some performance tests with your code!